Does right of way apply when two vehicles enter an intersection without either one stopping?
In Nevada, two cars approach an intersection at night time and none of the traffic lights are working. Both cars enter the intersection without stopping and collide.  One car hits the other broadside on the passenger side. When speaking to the police, the driver who was hit by the car which was coming from the right said that they came to a full stop before entering the intersection. The driver coming from the right told the police it wasn't possible to stop since no features of the intersection could be distinguished, and wound up getting the only ticket issued by the police.
The ticketed driver examined the dash cam video upon returning home which conclusively proves the other driver did not stop and therefore was lying to the police.  The dash cam was retrieved right after the accident and the driver did not volunteer information about the dash cam and was not asked any questions about the presence of any dash cam.
The police did not suspect anyone of impaired driving but gave sobriety tests as part of procedure. The sobriety test had two parts, and the driver who told the truth had a little trouble with the balance portion (presumably from the stress of the ordeal together with aging (57 years old) and natural clumsiness), despite having had not even one drop to drink. After the test the driver asked to take a breathalyzer but the police said they don't use them due to policy.
Will the video make any difference in the case of the liar or help the truthful driver in court despite having less than perfect balance?

what are you after?  Fairness in ticketing?  The video could be used to show equal fault for insurance.  In the US, traffic signals that are out of order should be treated as a 4-way stop.

“It wasn’t possible to stop”. If you can’t stop at a junction you need to approach it slower so you can.

No
It seems like the driver who was ticketed was cited for failing to yield to a vehicle already in the intersection. Given this was a T-bone collision the evidence for this is pretty overwhelming.
It’s also possible that the other driver failed to yield to the left when they should have. That would also be an offense but it’s possible for both drivers to be in the wrong. Wrongdoing by one party doesn’t excuse wrongdoing by another.
